# Unable to commit to gitbucket from cloud9 because of .c9 files

Tags: git, cloud9-ide

commit your changes or stash them before you can switch branches.

> error: The following untracked working tree files would be removed by checkout:
>           .c9/metadata/tab1
>           .c9/metadata/tab11
>           .c9/metadata/tab12
>           .c9/metadata/tab17
>           .c9/metadata/tab18
>           .c9/metadata/tab23
>           .c9/metadata/tab24
>           .c9/metadata/tab25
>           .c9/metadata/tab26
>           .c9/metadata/tab27
>           .c9/metadata/tab28
>           .c9/metadata/tab29
>           .c9/metadata/tab30
>           .c9/metadata/tab31
>           .c9/metadata/tab33
>           .c9/metadata/tab5
>           .c9/metadata/tab6
>           .c9/metadata/tab8
>           .c9/metadata/tab9
>           .c9/metadata/workspace/README.md
>           .c9/metadata/workspace/app/controllers/application_controller.rb
>           .c9/metadata/workspace/app/controllers/candy_pages_controller.rb
>           .c9/metadata/workspace/app/views/candy_pages/butterfinger.html.erb
>           .c9/metadata/workspace/app/views/candy_pages/home.html.erb
>           .c9/metadata/workspace/app/views/candy_pages/reeses.html.erb
>           .c9/metadata/workspace/app/views/candy_pages/skittles.html.erb
>           .c9/metadata/workspace/app/views/candy_pages/snickers.html.erb
>           .c9/metadata/workspace/app/views/layouts/application.html.erb
>           .c9/metadata/workspace/config/routes.rb
>           .c9/metadata/workspace/test/controllers/candy_pages_controller_test.rb

How do I get rid of these?  I've added

```
#Ignore all .c9 specific files
/.c9/
```

to my `.gitignore`, but that doesn't help what's already been tracked by git.

I've done a

```
$ git rm --cached .c9/ -r
```

but when I try to get back to my master

```
$ git checkout master
```

I'm unable to proceed because of the untracked working tree files...can someone help me with this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue I think is, you have these files already committed in some of your earlier commits and these are part of master now.

If that is the case, doing a `git log .c9/` will show you the commits as well. To work around this, just delete the files manually once, using `rm -rf .c9/`. In case you want to keep those files around, rename the `.c9` folder as something else (`mv .c9 .c9.bkp`). If you now do a `git status`, there are two possibilities, either there are no more files shown within the `.c9` directory, or there are some files which are coming as modified. In the latter case, do a `git checkout .c9` to re-generate only those files which are being tracked by git.

Now do a `git pull origin master`, to pull the latest master branch. Once the changes are pulled in, do

```
git rm -r --cached .c9/
echo ".c9*" >> .gitignore
git add .gitignore && git commit -m "Removing .c9 metadata files"
```

And now, push these changes back to the master branch using

```
git push origin master
```

When working on any other branch, rebase them master first (using `git rebase origin/master`) so that any `.c9` files committed in another branch doesn't creep back into master.

Now, you can restore your `.c9` folder from the backup we made if needed using  `mv .c9.bkp .c9`.

Comment: I did something wrong before the git pull origin master.  I get the errorerror: The following untracked working tree files would be overwritten by merge:
        .c9/metadata/tab0
Please move or remove them before you can merge.
Aborting

Comment: @studentss Quick question, are you getting the `.c9/metadata/tab0` error for a single file now? Are these errors happening on some kind of live instance?

Comment: yes, only one file now.  The rest were deleted with the rm -rf .c9/ I believe.I am using cloud9 and gitbucket.  Not sure what you mean by live instance in this case.  Does this help?

Comment: @studentss If you are okay making a dummy commit in your history, add and commit that file using `git add c9/ && git commit -m "adding c9"`. Now do a pull, the changes should get merged. Once the changes are merged locally, go ahead with steps for removing the files using `git rm --cached` and so on.

Comment: That worked.  Let me continue with what you wrote above.

Comment: Is it possible to get to where I was at the top of this question.  When I did the merge it wiped out my branch with my master.  I needed to go the other way; merge my branch into my master.  thanks.  I have my commit:  https://bitbucket.org/ssouza8/candy_ap/commits/ebad1f1c8e5d3952819d8abf6147d3f3fd03e00a?at=candy-pages

Comment: @studentss Yes, do a `git log`, figure out the SHA of the commit you want to go to, and then do `git  checkout -b new_branch_name SHA_to_checkout`.

Comment: o.k., I think I'm where I was at the top.  Anyway to verify that?  Anyway, I also added .c9/ and committed it, as when idid a checkout they were errors I had to resolve.  Now, before I go on, I want to $git checkout master and then $git merge candy_pages, and finally $git push.